# Get informations in a function to use it in another function DISCORD.PY

Tags: python, discord.py

i have a little problem with my code and i don't find any solutions,...

I write a code for my discord bot :

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        if message.content.startswith("!init"):
                if message.content.split()[1] == 'règles':
                        id_channel = 893442599019511829
                        embed = discord.Embed(title = 'Création bot', description = "par Archi's modo")
                        embed.add_field(name="Règlement de la LSPD", value="En cliquant sur l'icône ✅ vous reconnaissez avoir blablabla,...")
                        mess = await client.get_channel(id_channel).send(embed=embed)
                        await mess.add_reaction('✅')

@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    id_channel = 893442599019511829
    id_message = ?????
    role_a_donner =  "zabloublou"
    message_id = payload.message_id
    member = payload.member
    if message_id == id_message:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
 
        if payload.emoji.name == '✅': 
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=str(role_a_donner))
        else:
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.role, name=payload.emoji.name)
 
        if role is not None:
            if member is not None:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                channel = client.get_channel(id_channel)
                await channel.send(member.mention)
```

And i don't know how can i get id of the message sended by the bot to use it in my function on_raw_reaction_add

Can someone help me please  ?

Answer (score -2):

You should consider using `wait_for` instead for this kind of use.Your method is mostly used for reaction roles.
Here is an example of wait_for reaction grabbed from [discord.py docs for wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$thumb'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('')
        else:
            await channel.send('')
```